# How to update a config file section using git config?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-config

I need to add `branch = super_foo` to the existing `superproject` section in test_config file:

```
$ cat .test_config
[superproject "mysuper"]
    url = https://server.com/test/mysuper

[submodule "tsn-inc"]
    url = url = https://server.com/test/foo_s
    branch = foo
```

This works:

```
git config -f .test_config --add superproject.mysuper.branch super_foo
```

But, "mysuper" is not a known value, so I tried below as there will be only one superproject section.

```
git config -f .test_config --add superproject.*.branch super_foo
```

it added a new section as below:

```
[superproject "*"]
    branch = super_foo
```

Instead, I want to add branch to the existing superproject section, is there a way to do this?

Comment: I do not know what you are doing (caused by my own lack of knowledge), but what speaks against editing the file in a text editor? Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve with that? I uninformedly doubt that `branch` has a meaning for `superproject`

Answer (score 1):

When writing configuration `git config` wants the exact key - no patterns, no regex is allowed here. So you have to deduce the `mysuper` part somehow.

You can extract a list of `superproject` sections:

```
git config --name-only --get-regex '^superproject\.' | sed  -r 's/^[^.]+\.(.*)\.[^.]+$/\1/' | sort -u
```

If you know that there is exactly one `superproject` section in you config or are just interested in the first one then you can set the value in a script like this:

```
subsection=$(
    git config --name-only --get-regex '^superproject\.' |
    sed -rn '1,1s/^[^.]+\.(.*)\.[^.]+$/\1/p'
)
git config super --add "superproject.$subsection.branch" super_foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
super_name=$(git config -f .test_config --name-only --get-regexp superproject | cut -d. -f2)
```

This gives me super project name.

```
git config -f .test_config --add superproject.$super_name.branch super_foo
```

This did it.